# Get specific data from Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

I am having issue in getting correct data from database.

I have a PRODUCTS table with 3 columns:

```
id, Name and Category
```

AND, I have a DATA table with 3 columns:

```
id, Name, products_id(F.K)
```

Now, suppose I have in my Products table one entry with values

```
(1, "iPhone 6S", "Mobiles")
```

AND, in Data table I have multiple entries of Names:

```
iPhone 6s 16GB, 
iPhone 6s 32GB, 
iPhone 6s Plus 16GB, 
iPhone 6s Plus 32GB
```

and so on. Now I want `iPhone 6s` only, not `iPhone 6s Plus`.

In code below I am updating products_id where it matches Name of products with Name of DATA. By doing this I am getting both `iPhone 6s` and `iPhone 6s Plus`

I want only `iPhone 6s`.

```
@P1 = Product.where(id: 1).pluck(:Name)
@arr = @P1[0].split
Data.where("Name like ? AND Name like ? AND Name like ? AND Name like ? ", 
            "%#{@arr[0]}%", 
            "%#{@arr[1]}%", 
            "%#{@arr[2]}%", 
            "%#{@arr[3]}%").update_all(products_id:1)
```

Now using above code I get products_id in front of iPhone 6s and iPhone 6s Plus. I dont want it placed in front of iPhone 6s Plus. Any other approach of doing it can also be helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Data.where(" name REGEXP ?", 'your_regex_here')

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match exactly on the name, search on the full string rather than with a like.

```
 name = Product.where(id: 1).pluck(:Name)
 Data.where(Name: name).updated_all(products_id: 1)
```

Comment: This will match full string "iPhone 6s" only, In some entries I have like "iPhone 6s 16GB"